# How to find the elements of a matrix > 0 in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm curious - is there a single Matlab command to return the elements in a Matrix that are > 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code returns all positive elements of matrix `A`:

```
A(find(A > 0))
```

or in short form as proposed by Gunther Struyf:

```
A(A > 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

The find function will return the indices of elements that are not zero.

```
ind = find(A > 0);
```

is what you're looking for...

Comment: Note that this is slower than logical indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Or the command that was specially designed for this purpose: 'nonzeros'

```
nz_A = nonzeros(A);
```